# How to install a Bafang brake sensor on a road bike with drop bars and V brakes?

Tags: road-bike, brakes, electric-bike

I'm planning to install an e-bike kit on a road bike with drop levers.

[image: drop handlebars with an attached stem and brake levers, not attached to a bike and with no bar tape or cables/hoses]

You must install a sensor for the motor to stop providing power during braking. However they are all used for normal brakes. They work by having a magnet close to a sensor:
[image: Annotated photo of the right brake lever on a straight bar; a magnet is attached to the base of the lever and a sensor is positioned immediately beside it on the brake lever mount]

I see two possible solutions:

- Can you put the sensor and the magnetic directly down to the V-brakes?
- You can also get a gear cable sensor, can you use that on that on the brake wires?

Answer (score 2):

I've built quite a few bafang kits (though never with drop bar levers). IMHO, you don't need the sensors. The motor stops pretty much immediately once you stop pedaling. I'd suggest leaving them off and try it out without, and only continue that path if you think you might need them.

Should you still want them, yes, you can attach them to the v brakes themselves, although it doesn't really feel right to me. I assume you already figured out that all the sensor does is to detect when the magnet moves away from the sensor. The brake cable sensor would work regardless of the type of lever.